# JSX/Photoshop: Selecting Initial History Snapshot - Looking for a shorter way

Tags: history, snapshot, photoshop-script, jsx

I have a piece of code that selects the initial state (snapshot) of the active document.

I wonder if there exist a short way to achieve the same goal.

Here is the actual script:

```
var myDoc = app.activeDocument.name;
var doc = app.activeDocument.historyStates.length;

alert("History States : " + doc);


function firstStep(enabled, withDialog) {
  if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
    return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref1 = new ActionReference();
    ref1.putName(cTID('SnpS'), myDoc);
    desc1.putReference(cTID('null'), ref1);
    executeAction(cTID('slct'), desc1, dialogMode); 
    alert("Selected Initial State");                
};

firstStep();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Untested, but maybe worth a try: `docRef.activeHistoryState = docRef.historyStates.getByName('Snapshot 0');`

Comment: It works! I must tweak it a bit, but it's the right way. Many thaks.

Comment: I may put it as an answer later for all to see without scrabbling through the Comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines should work for you:

```
docRef.activeHistoryState = docRef.historyStates.getByName('Snapshot 0');
```

Comment: The final vession: var myDoc = app.activeDocument.name;

function step1(enabled, withDialog) {
 app.activeDocument.activeHistoryState = app.activeDocument.historyStates.getByName(myDoc);      
};
step1();